Powershell error: sometimes denies me access to folders
I have a script that audits folders to ensure it has files in it. In doing so I use get-childItem to lets say grab and post onto the CLI from the files located in C:\Documents or whatever. But half the time I get an error saying Access Denied and it mentions permissions, and then sometimes if I re-run the script it runs normally and displays the files I was searching for. Its a 50/50.
Any reason why this may be happening?
BTW I'm using a domain admin account.
Tried checking Mcafee Epo and checking folder permissions and file permissions are normal to run, write, execute, traverse, etc.

Welcome to SO, user24165515. Please read the information under https://stackoverflow.com/help to learn how SO works. Please edit your question and copy/paste the commands you are using and any error messages as text into the question. No pictures.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
